# Convert array of tuples to array to array of strings python

Tags: python, numpy

I have an array of tuple, for example like this `array([[(), (6,), (8,6), ()]])` with a shape of `(1, 4)` and I want to convert the tuples into strings `array([['()', '(6,)', '(8,6)', '()']])`. What's the best way to do that? Thanks

Comment: This is essentially a list and string task.  `numpy` doesn't add anything.

Answer (score 0):

Use `map` function:

```py
In [1]: array = np.array([[(), (1,2), (8,6), ()]], dtype=object)

In [2]: np.array([list(map(str, array[0]))])
Out[2]: array([['()', '(1, 2)', '(8, 6)', '()']], dtype='<U6')
```

`map` function, iterates through an interable and runs the function on all items inside it and finally. It returns a generator; So if you want to get a list, you have to use a list comprehension or `list` function.

Comment: This is just as good as the `np.vectorize` answer, and especially without the `np.array` wrapper will be faster.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a vectorized version of the str constructor and then use it on the array:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[(), (6,), (8,6), ()]])

asString = np.vectorize(str)

print(asString(a))
[['()' '(6,)' '(8, 6)' '()']]
```